# Turning on Airplane Mode on an iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch, battery-life, ios

After I upgraded to iOS 4, there is an Airplane mode in the Settings on my 2nd generation iPod Touch.

Will turning on Airplane Mode improve its battery life noticeably?

Comment: Sorry, questions about electronic devices like the ipod touch are [off-topic](http://superuser.com/faq) on Super User. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **YES**.

Turning wifi off means the device won't look for networks to join, so it does less. So you get more battery life for other things.

On the other hand, iOS has some significant power management improvements that have resulted in better battery life for me (on my 3GS) anyway, so the improvement might be minimal on top of what's already there.

I wouldn't worry about it unless you're often away from a charging station.

Comment: -1 for answering an off-topic question. Please refrain from doing that in the future. You can find more information about what is on or off-topic in the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to save battery life, turning on Airplane Mode will noticeably increase battery life, especially if you had enabled "ask to join networks."

Even just turning off that option and leaving WiFi on will make a difference.

Comment: Please don't answer an off-topic question. -1